# Trigraphs in a comment, converted in c++11, ignored in c++17

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Consider the following piece of code (notice the comment):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 1; // <-- Why??/
    x += 1;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

To compile this program, I am using the GNU C++ Compiler `g++`:

```
$ g++ --version // g++ (Ubuntu 6.5.0-1ubuntu1~16.04) 6.5.0 20181026
```

Now, when compiling this for *C++11* and *C++17*, I get different results (and warnings).

For C++11, `g++ -std=c++11 trigraph.cpp -Wall`:

```
trigraph.cpp:5:26: warning: trigraph ??/ converted to \ [-Wtrigraphs]
         int x = 1; // <-- Why??/

trigraph.cpp:5:16: warning: multi-line comment [-Wcomment]
         int x = 1; // <-- Why??/
                    ^
$ ./a.out
1
```

For C++17, `g++ -std=c++17 trigraph.cpp -Wall`:

```
trigraph.cpp:5:26: warning: trigraph ??/ ignored, use -trigraphs to enable [-Wtrigraphs]
     int x = 1; // <-- Why??/

$ ./a.out
2
```

After reading a bit about trigraphs, I understand that they were removed in C++17, thus ignored by the compiler as shown in the example above. However, in the case of C++11, even when it's in a comment it was converted!

Now, I can see how that would affect the code if the trigraph was in  a character string for instance. But, in this example, shouldn't it be ignored since it's in a comment?

After removing the trailing forward slash ("/") from the comment, all warnings disappeared. My question is what did exactly happen here? Why the output is different?

Comment: Beside of knowing that something like trigraphs exists, I had wondered that they are considered even in comments. Hence, I quickly re-called [Phases of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases): Phase 1: 3) Trigraph sequences are replaced by corresponding single-character representations. (until C++17), Phase 2: 1) Whenever backslash appears at the end of a line (immediately followed by the newline character), both backslash and newline are deleted, Phase 3: 3) Each comment is replaced by one space character. - This `// <-- Why??/` is really underhanded. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff thank you for the link, and also for summarizing its content to fit the question. Indeed `// <-- Why??/` was tricky!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trigraphs are are very old way to insert certain characters into code, which were possibly not available on all keybords. For full list, see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative).

In your example, you accidentally created one of the trigraphs `??/`, which is translated into `\`. Trailing `\` has a special meaning - it tells the compiler to ignore line break and treat next line as part of the current line.

Your code would be translated like this:

```
int x = 1; // <-- Why??/
x += 1; 

int x = 1; // <-- Why\
x += 1;

int x = 1; // <-- Why x += 1;
```

This is what the warnings actually mean. 
Trigraph was interpreted and changed into `\`, and it created a multi line comment, even though you used `//`.

Now, trigraphs became **depracated** in C++11 and were **removed** from standard in C++17. 
This means, when compiling in C++11 your trigraph was translated, but in C++17 it was ignored (and compiler sent you a note that you can still enable them).

Comment: So the `x += 1;` statement got stripped out during preprocessing, makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The trigraph `??/` gets converted by the compiler to `\` before actual compilation happens (i.e. before comments are removed).

So these lines

```
int x = 1; // <-- Why??/
x += 1;
```

get converted to

```
int x = 1; // <-- Why\
x += 1;
```

A backslash at the end of a line appends the next line to it. So it becomes

```
int x = 1; // <-- Why    x += 1;
```

Which moves the statement `x+=1;` into the comment and thus it is not compiled.

When you remove the trailing `/`, it is not a trigraph anymore (sincce it's now only `??`) and nothing special happens.

Answer (score 3):

If `??/` is converted to `\` then `??//` would be converted to `\/`.

Or `//` also starts a comment, so the application rule for trigraphs comes first, and only after that does the compiler check whether it's a comment or not.